# Flutter) When accessing an album on iOS, the permission request does not appear

Tags: flutter, permissions

I am using the permission_handler package. The version is 9.0.1.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFNITIONS'] ||=[
        '$(inherited)',
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1' 
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

My Podfile is the same as above.

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>blahblahblah!</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>blahblahblah!</string>
```

I also put values ​​in NSCameraUsageDescription and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist.

```dart
var photoPermission = await Permission.photos.status;
if (!photoPermission.isGranted) {
    await Permission.photos.request();
}
```

When debugging while setting a breakpoint, I can see the program entering the  `await Permission.photos.request();` code. However, the permission request window does not appear.

I also looked for the package's GitHub issue page, but couldn't solve it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the third library Compiling wield, It works fine by editing the iOS plugin part source code a little

---

seen from the source code:

[image: 111]

in file `PhotoPermissionStrategy.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PermissionStrategy.h"

#if PERMISSION_PHOTOS

#import <Photos/Photos.h>

@interface PhotoPermissionStrategy : NSObject <PermissionStrategy>
-(instancetype)initWithAccessAddOnly:(BOOL) addOnly;
@end

#else

#import "UnknownPermissionStrategy.h"
@interface PhotoPermissionStrategy : UnknownPermissionStrategy
@end

#endif
```

turn the above into

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PermissionStrategy.h"

#if 1

#import <Photos/Photos.h>

...
```

And in file `PhotoPermissionStrategy.m`

turn

```
#import "PhotoPermissionStrategy.h"

#if PERMISSION_PHOTOS

@implementation PhotoPermissionStrategy{
    bool addOnlyAccessLevel;
}

...
```

to

```
#import "PhotoPermissionStrategy.h"

#if 1

@implementation PhotoPermissionStrategy{
    bool addOnlyAccessLevel;
}

...
```

---

easy to debug by logging the source code